# Execute two actions successively using bpy.app.timers.register(every_0.1_seconds)

Tags: python, scripting

What I want to do is to execute two functions, each function is like one action, the second action should be performed only when the first one is finished.
In my example I have a cube, and I want it to move in x axis, then the y axis.
So to have a smouth movement I used `bpy.app.timers.register(every_0.1_seconds)`
My code example:

```
import bpy
x=0
y=0

def action1():
    global x
    if x<10:
        x+=0.1
        bpy.data.objects['Cube'].location[0]=x
        print('x')
    return 0.1


def action2():
    global y
    if y<10:
        y+=0.1
        bpy.data.objects['Cube'].location[1]=y
        print('y')
    return 0.1

bpy.app.timers.register(action1)
bpy.app.timers.register(action2)
```

Comment: So you want your object to move to x = 10 by 0.1 increment every 0.1 second, then when it has reached x = 10, move to y = 10 by 0.1 increment every 0.1 second ? Why not use a single callback ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  still doesn't work !

Comment: you are registering both timers "at the same time". Python does not stop after the first register function.

Comment: Oh I see thank you for reply @Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out:

```
  import bpy

x=0
y=0

def action1():
    global x
    if x<1:
        x+=0.1
        bpy.data.objects['Cube'].location[0]=x
        print('x', x)
        return 0.1
    else:
        bpy.app.timers.register(action2)
        

def action2():
    global y
    if y<1:
        y+=0.1
        bpy.data.objects['Cube'].location[1]=y
        print('y', y)
        return 0.1
        
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].location = (0,0,0)
bpy.app.timers.register(action1)
```

of course Gorgious is right - you don't need two timers.
But if you want to use 2 timers, my code works.

[image]

Comment: It works ! Thank you, just one more question there is a way to call multiple functions successively using just one Timer, something like a Queue ?

Comment: @AlecDev you should be able to do it with `if` `else` `elif`, if you replace the `else: ...` in Chris' answer here by the contents of `action2` the script should behave exactly the same

Comment: Yeah you're right but in my case I need to execute functions one by one without any conditions, for example one to move object in x axis, then the second function to y axis @Gorgious

Comment: Hi Alex, i really would prefer if you ask another question so that other people would find your "new" question as well. I wrote another answer, but i am not sure whether you want it that way

Comment: @AlecDev well if you can say "execute this then execute that", I'm sure you can find a way to use an `if ... else` somewhere

Comment: Yeah it's true, thank you @Gorgious

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer to your question in your comment, although i am not sure whether this is what you want...

```
import bpy
x=0
y=0


def timerFunc():
    global x
    if x<1:
        moveX()
        return 0.1
    else:
        global y
        if y<1:
            moveY()
            return 0.1
        
    
def moveX():
    global x
    x+=0.1
    bpy.data.objects['Cube'].location[0]=x
    print('x', x)
    
def moveY():
    global y
    y+=0.1
    bpy.data.objects['Cube'].location[1]=y
    print('y', y)
        
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].location = (0,0,0)

bpy.app.timers.register(timerFunc)
```

Comment: Yeah something like that thank you @Chris

Comment: you are welcome